# Render GUI to Image in Memory

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Is it somehow possible to render a GUI to a BufferedImage or another kind of memory image without displaying it on a screen ?

I know this will loose all kinds of hardware acceleration, but for a simple GUI that is refreshed only once or twice a second this should not be an issue.

Already tried to get JavaFX to output an image, but i can't find a way to leave out rendering on a screen first. Does anyone know a way to do this with JavaFX or Swing ?

It is no problem to draw a simple GUI myself using simple image manipulations, but then i would have to do it all by hand and using Swing or FX would make it much easier.

Edit:
To make it a bit more clear, i don't have an active display, but i can save an image which then gets displayed through other means. To be exact its a raspberry pi, but without a primary display device with a connected tft display using the GPIO port. So i can't render the UI directly to a display device, but need to create an image that i can save at a specific location. All methods i have tried so far need a primary display device.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, the term for this is called *double buffering*, and is possible. It depends on how you're handling your rendering though. Right now, this question is too broad. Choose either FX or Swing (or a combination of the two), and be more specific (whats the difference between outputting an image and rendering it in this case? Does your GUI contain components? ect..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to render a GUI to an image offscreen.

Here is a sample using JavaFX, with example image output as below:

[image]

The example works by rendering the chart to an scene which is not added to any window and no window (Stage in JavaFX terminology) is ever shown.  The [snapshot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) method is used to take a snapshot of the node and then [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) utilities are used to save the snapshot to disk.

Rendering of the offscreen scene will be hardware accelerated if the underlying hardware/software platform supports it.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class OffscreenImageRecorder extends Application {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OffscreenImageRecorder.class.getName());

    private static final String IMAGE_TYPE = "png";
    private static final String IMAGE_FILENAME = "image." + IMAGE_TYPE;
    private static final String WORKING_DIR = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    private static final String IMAGE_PATH = new File(WORKING_DIR, IMAGE_FILENAME).getPath();

    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    private final Random random = new Random();

    private final int CHART_SIZE = 400;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Parent chart = createChart();
        Image  image = snapshot(chart);
        exportPng(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), IMAGE_PATH);

        Platform.exit();
    }

    private Parent createChart() {
        // create a chart.
        final PieChart chart = new PieChart();
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", random.nextInt(30)),
                        new PieChart.Data("Oranges", random.nextInt(30)),
                        new PieChart.Data("Plums", random.nextInt(30)),
                        new PieChart.Data("Pears", random.nextInt(30)),
                        new PieChart.Data("Apples", random.nextInt(30))
                );
        chart.setData(pieChartData);
        chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits - " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));

        // It is important for snapshots that the chart is not animated
        // otherwise we could get a snapshot of the chart before the
        // data display has been animated in.
        chart.setAnimated(false);

        chart.setMinSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        chart.setPrefSize(CHART_SIZE, CHART_SIZE);
        chart.setMaxSize(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE, Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        return chart;
    }

    private Image snapshot(final Parent sourceNode) {
        // Note: if the source node is not in a scene, css styles will not
        // be applied during a snapshot which may result in incorrect rendering.
        final Scene snapshotScene = new Scene(sourceNode);

        return sourceNode.snapshot(
                new SnapshotParameters(),
                null
        );
    }

    private void exportPng(BufferedImage image, String filename) {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, IMAGE_TYPE, new File(filename));

            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Wrote image to: " + filename);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that you could get the graphics of scene elements before the scene is shown. Allways thought you had to do the primaryStage.setScene(...); primaryStage.show(); to create the graphics. Now just have to figure out how to create the Application object as background thread instead of main thread. But thats another topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could create a frame and position it on a invisible location (using Swing in this example):

```
frame = new JFrame("Invisible frame");
frame.setBounds(-1000, 100, 640, 480);
```

Comment: That would still take over the graphical output on a rapsberry which i want to avoid.